Modelinstance rotation breaks apart after translating modelinstance foward in LiBGDX project
The following code rotates my modelinstance about its centerpoint y-axis. HOWEVER, when I move the modelinstance foward the rotation gets all wrong! I am not sure what is happening. I need for the rotation to work the same always NOT just before I start moving the modelinstance foward!
Here how I apply my rotation after pressing the D key:
BoundingBox bbox = new BoundingBox();
                    ThreeDWithMultipleScreensGame.gameMainPlayerReference.calculateBoundingBox(bbox);
                    bbox.mul(/*node_.globalTransform*/ThreeDWithMultipleScreensGame.gameMainPlayerReference.transform);
                    Vector3 centerVector_ = new Vector3();
                    bbox.getCenter(centerVector_);

                    Gdx.app.log("okcenter","here: " + centerVector_.toString());


                    if(true){

                        Matrix4 m4 = new Matrix4();
                        m4.set(ThreeDWithMultipleScreensGame.gameMainPlayerReference.transform);
                        //m4.translate(10,0,10).rotate(0,1,0,-20f*LevelOneScreen.playerRotationSpeed*deltatime).translate(-10,0,-10);
                        m4.translate(centerVector_).rotate(0,1,0,-20f*LevelOneScreen.playerRotationSpeed*deltatime).translate(-1f*centerVector_.x,-1f*centerVector_.y,-1f*centerVector_.z);
                        Gdx.app.log("multiply","we have: " + centerVector_.cpy().scl(-1f).toString());
                        ThreeDWithMultipleScreensGame.gameMainPlayerReference.transform.set(m4);
                        ThreeDWithMultipleScreensGame.gameMainPlayerReference.calculateTransforms();

                    }

And, here is how I translate my modelinstance foward:
vecyr.set(0,0,0); //clearing vecyr... important
                    mat4_.set(ThreeDWithMultipleScreensGame.gameMainPlayerReference.transform);
                    vecyr.z-=deltatime*LevelOneScreen.playerSpeed;
                    mat4_.translate(vecyr);
                    ThreeDWithMultipleScreensGame.gameMainPlayerReference.transform.set(mat4_);
                    ThreeDWithMultipleScreensGame.gameMainPlayerReference.calculateTransforms();
                    ThreeDWithMultipleScreensGame.gameMainPlayerReference.transform.getTranslation(ThreeDWithMultipleScreensGame.playerCurrentPosition);


camera.position.add(vecyr);
                    
camera.lookAt(10f,0,ThreeDWithMultipleScreensGame.playerCurrentPosition.z-7.5f);
                    camera.update();

Why does the rotation only work before I start moving my modelinstance foward?
